# Vlookup error with drop down

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have created an expense sheet with month drop down list.

When I choose months from January to November, the data shows correctly.

But for December, it's incorrect.

November:

[image: November]

December:

[image: December]

Sheet3:

[[image: Sheet3 data][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qK39.jpg)

Below is the formula I am using:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B$1,Sheet3!A:Q,MATCH($A6,Sheet3!$A$1:$Q$1,0)),0)
```

Comment: please add some sample data if you want us to help...

Comment: The structure of your Sheet3 would be interesting, as the formula references it.

Comment: You need 0 or False as a last argument of VLOOKUP:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B$1,Sheet3!A:Q,MATCH($A6,Sheet3!$A$1:$Q$1,0),0),0)`

Comment: Thank you mgonet it is working now